# Android Chrome onplay event not working

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm trying to make an automatic start of next audio-element from another and hit the trouble.

The idea is that i assigned a function to "onplay" event of every audio-element. This function gets the object(this) of clicked element, checks some conditions, launches next function and further passing the object(this) of clicked element to it.

```
function clickWrapper(triggeredObject) {
    if (mode == 'normal') {
        triggeredObject.onended = function() {playNextSong(triggeredObject)
    }
}
```

The next function is trying to get the id of next element, and assign itself to "onended" event of that next audio element to achieve recursive playing of all elements.

```
function playNextSong(NowPlayingSong) {
    var nextSongId;
        for (i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
            if (playlist[i] == NowPlayingSong.id) {
                nextSongId = playlist[i+1];
            };
        };
    var nextSong = document.getElementById(nextSongId);
    nextSong.play();
    nextSong.onended = function() {playNextSong(this)};
}
```

On PC the folowing code works as expected. But the question is how to make it work on Android Chrome! Because it's just not triggers these events on my opinion.

Perhaps all "solution" is wrong but then i don't know how to achieve recursive plaing of all audio elements on a page.

You can test this code on novk.tk/audio

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
That's a "user control" feature.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178297

To make, say a player, we need once user clicked - get and hold this event in js and not loose it. make everything on your own with a single program flow without other html-elements interactions. So sad. :(

my entire concept goes to hell.